# Vim: Textwrap without leading characters

Tags: vim, word-wrap, autoformatting

I am writing a bulletted list in VIM, and have set textwidth=79 to hard wrap the lines.  As I write the list, I would like for each carriage return to produce a new bullet and for the wrapped lines to not have bullets.  However, VIM is doing the opposite (bullets on wrapped lines, no bullets after carriage return).  I would like:

```
* Item 1 - The text for this line is too long and
  so is wrapped to the next line.
* Item 2 - Typing a carriage return after item 1
  should produce the bullet for this item.
```

However, VIM does this:

```
* Item 1 - The text for this line is too long and
* so is wrapped to the next line.
Item 2 - Typing a carriage return after item 1
should produce the bullet for this line.
```

I have autoindent on, cindent off, and formatexpr is an empty string.  I understand and like the auto-inserted '*' behavior for C-style comments, but would like different behavior for text filetypes.  Is there a setting that allows this?

Comment: You can use `gq` to format the text as you want (that's what I usually do), but it seems to work for `-` only (and not for `*`)

Comment: I have been able to get pretty close by settings "comments=fb:*" and "formatoptions=tcq".  This wraps correctly, but does not add the bullet after carriage returns.  I thought that adding 'r' to the formatoptions sounded like it should do this, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I think you get half of what you want with `:set fo+=r comments=fb:*`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
set formatoptions=tn autoindent
let &formatlistpat='^\s*\(\d\+[\]:.)}\t ]\|[*-]\s\)\s*'
```

The *n* flag in formatoptions triggers the formatting of lists that you are after but the default setting of formatlistpat only handles numbered lists. The one above adds bullets of either `*` or `-`.